# foreach rows of my table and update my ROW_NUMBER column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I would like to create a script pl/sql where I can modify the value of my column ROW_NUMBER (the first time the value of ROW_NUMBER equal NULL).

This is the structure of my table 'A' :

```
CREATE TABLE A
   (
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "NUM" NUMBER(10,0)
   )
```

I would like to foreach all rows of table A and increment my Column 'NUM' by 1 if Column 'NAME' equal 'DEB'.

I would like to get the result like :

[image]

I created one pl/sql script :

```
DECLARE
 INcrmt NUMBER(4):=1;
 line WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ%ROWTYPE;--before fetch it returns 0
 CURSOR c_select IS
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER,VALUE FROM WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ;
BEGIN
 OPEN c_select;
  LOOP
   FETCH c_select INTO line;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(line.VALUE);
   if line.VALUE like '%DEB%'
   then
    UPDATE WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ SET ROW_NUMBER = INcrmt WHERE VALUE=line.VALUE;
    INcrmt := INcrmt + 1;
   end if;
   if line.VALUE not like '%DEB%'
    then
    UPDATE WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ SET ROW_NUMBER = INcrmt WHERE VALUE=line.VALUE;
   end if;
   EXIT WHEN c_select%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_select;
 COMMIT;
END;

DECLARE
 INcrmt NUMBER(4):=1;
 line WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ%ROWTYPE;--before fetch it returns 0
 CURSOR c_select IS
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER,VALUE FROM WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ;
BEGIN
 OPEN c_select;
  LOOP
   FETCH c_select INTO line;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(line.VALUE);
   if line.VALUE like '%DEB%'
   then
    UPDATE WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ SET ROW_NUMBER = INcrmt WHERE VALUE=line.VALUE;
    INcrmt := INcrmt + 1;
   end if;
   if line.VALUE not like '%DEB%'
    then
    UPDATE WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ SET ROW_NUMBER = INcrmt WHERE VALUE=line.VALUE;
   end if;
   EXIT WHEN c_select%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_select;
 COMMIT;
END;
```

but this is not work well , please take a look at what it gives me as result :

[image]

please anybody can help me

Comment: My first thought when reading this question was "yuck," and my second thought was "use an auto increment column."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what you mean by yack

Comment: @Abderrahim you want to increment rownumber +1 when the values equal to DEB or FIN ?

Comment: @Moudiz I want to increment rownumber +1 when I reach the line which has DEB. Once reach line which has DEB increment rownumber +1

Comment: @Abderrahim is gorden linoff answer is helpful ?

Comment: @Moudiz really I didn't understand him although his answer sound useful . I am not familiar with this :( . I like to fix my script

Comment: I must say your Oracle DBMS works perfect even on this macaroni. First of all your rows' VALUE field is not unique so UPDATE WORK_ODI.TEST_SEQ SET ROW_NUMBER = INcrmt WHERE VALUE=line.VALUE; can affect multiple rows. This is why all the "BlaBla***" rows have ROW_NUMBER=3. The second problem is you suppose your rows to be ordered but they are not - their order is not predictable in common case. And I heard GoogleTranslate knows what @TimBiegeleisen meant by "yuck".

Comment: @diziaq I understand yuck meaning now I am sorry because I am not familiar with pl/sql. thanks for your comment

Comment: In order to number the records as described there should be some inherent order already, say a date or an ascending number in your records. As is, `select * from test_sql` could give you 'DEB1' as the first record or the last or at any other position, because you haven't specified any ORDER BY clause. But then, if you already had a sort criterion to get 'DEB1' at position 1, what sense would it make to store the row number in the table? You could always generate it from the data given, so storing it would be redundant. (Or are you only trying to create initial values you'll change afterwards?)

Answer (score 6):

First, you should have an `Aid` column of some sort.  In Oracle 12+, you can use an identity.  In earlier versions, you can use a sequence.  This provides an ordering for the rows in the table, based on insert order.

Second, you can do what you want on output:

```
select a.*,
       sum(case when a.name like 'DEB%' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by aid) as row_number
from a;
```

If you really need to keep the values in the table, then you can use a `merge` statement to assign values to existing rows (the `aid` column is very handy for this).  You will need a trigger afterwards to maintain it.

My suggestion is to do the calculation on the data, rather than storing the value in the data.  Maintaining the values with `update`s and `delete`s seems like a real pain.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer , I am not familiar with this I will try to understand it and then return to you

Comment: hm the client don't like trigger :(